# How to update "Fixed In" field when integrating Rally with Subversion?

Tags: ruby, svn, rally

After integrating Rally with Subversion our User stories, Tasks and Defects in Rally are automatically updated after code is committed to the repository. However only the following fields are updated:

- Changesets
- State
- Todo (for Tasks)

An important field that should also be updated is the "Fixed In" fields for Defects, which should contain the revision number of the fix. I contacted Rally Customer Support but the response was that expanding the update functionality of Rally artifacts is not currently being considered.

Any suggestions on addressing this?

Answer (score 1):

Actually it is trivial to change the Ruby script provided by Rally as a post-hook for Subversion. Even though this may change for a future version, for **RallyConnectorForSvn-3.5** simply edit **lib/scm_connector.rb** and add the following line in the **construct_artifact_fields** method, inside the ***if state*** block:

```
if type == :defect  && state == 'Fixed'
    update_fields[:fixed_in_build] = @changeset_number
end
```

Hopefully this will be added to the next release of the connector.